# Unable to kill process in linux

Tags: python, linux, kill-process, ps, sigkill

I'm trying to kill some running process, but nothing seems working.

I've tried `kill -9 pid` `kill -15 pid` `kill -SIGTERM pid` `killall service-name` but nothing is able to kill/stop these processes.

after trying all these commands, if I enter `ps aux | grep airflow` it returns following results.

```
2018-02-17 10:57:13 mubin:~> ps aux | grep airflow
mubin  10123  0.0  0.0 103364   848 pts/2    S+   10:57   0:00 grep airflow
mubin  20740  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Feb15   0:02 [airflow]
mubin  21889  0.0  0.2 461968 77864 ?        D    Feb15   0:00 /anaconda3/bin/python /anaconda3/bin/airflow scheduler
mubin  21890  0.0  0.2 462236 77752 ?        D    Feb15   0:00 /anaconda3/bin/python /anaconda3/bin/airflow scheduler
```

I also tried to switch user to `root` and tried all kill commands, nothing worked.

can anyone suggest what could be the issue.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `D` in the STAT column means

> `D`    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)

(see `man ps`).

Comment: How do I kill all these with `D`?

Comment: "uninterruptible" means it can't be interrupted. You can't kill it.

Comment: Yeah I got the point, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If after:

> I've tried kill -9 pid kill -15 pid kill -SIGTERM pid killall service-name but nothing is able to kill/stop these processes.

and

> I also tried to switch user to `root` and tried all kill commands, nothing worked.

I suggest you just manually restart your computer.

Comment: seems so, in that way, I need to start a lot of service manually and may be need to remount the cluster FS as well :(

Comment: yea, it kinda feel bad, but sometimes one is left with no any other option.

Answer (score 0):

you can use kill 9 pid command for to kill  particular process and kill all for all processes

Comment: You can't kill a process if it's in uninterruptible sleep.